# Why won't my custom build PC boot?

Tags: memory, bios, desktop-computer, computer-building, overclocking

I built a new PC for the first time in a while.  Everything seemed to go well.  It boots to bios and everything seems good.  But when I try and actually boot off a bootable Windows or Linux USB drive (or just insert no bootable media), nothing happens for 10-15 seconds, and then the system just reboots.

[Here are the components for reference.](https://newegg.io/e7ed529)

I've verified the boot media works on other computers.  I've also verified the reboot doesn't happen if I'm in the bios (so I don't think it's something like a heat issue).

There are a couple strange things.

1. The PSU fan stops spinning after power on, which I don't think I've seen in the past, but everything is cool so I don't know that it's actually a problem.
2. My memory I believe should be at a speed of 5600.  It's reading as 3600 in the bios.  Also, the motherboard says it supports "5600(OC) ", which I believe means some overclocking is required.  This is the first time I've bought a RAM / Motherboard combo that requires that, and I don't really know what I'm doing there.  I've changed nothing, so maybe that's my issue?  I did see there is something called "Extreme Memory Profile (XMP/EXPO) and when I turn that on, it seems to recognize the "DDR5-5600" and shows some timing.  However, when I reboot with this on the system won't boot at all, not even to bios.  (**EDIT: I set a memory multiplier to 56 and now my RAM speed shows as 5614, which is roughly correct.  I still can't boot, though.**)

Is my memory problem the most likely cause of my inability to boot?  (Seems like I need to get it sorted regardless.)  Does anyone know how I should go about making it work?  Or should I send the RAM back and buy something slower?

Or might something else be going wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, it could be that your Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) has Legacy mode disabled but your Bootable USB is created for Legacy support. Check if there's an option to enable Legacy Support (It could be named as CSM as well) in BIOS and test again. Alternatively try creating Bootable USB for UEFI mode and check again.

Comment: I verified most of the media I'm using is UEFI, and that that's enabled.  I tried turning SecureBoot off, but that made no difference.  When I'd turn on CSM and reboot, it be off the next time I went back in to the EUFI.  I'm now fairly convinced the problem is not really a boot problem, but maybe an actual hardware issue like RAM.  Because I haven't been able to boot anything at all regardless of settings (USB I tried are Linux, Windows11, memtest86, and also Windows 11 via DVD)

Comment: Generally if there's HW incompatibility system would not POST and boot to BIOS screen. Is there any option in BIOS to load system or optimized defaults, if so try that. Also if there's an update to BIOS consider updating it to the latest version and recheck.

Comment: I've reset to default settings many times.  I've also tried changing most every setting that could have to do with boot, but no luck.  I tried to update firmware, and everything looks like it went well, but the firmware number doesn't actually change after reboot.  I think the MB is just no good.  I'm going to send it back.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a few different things going on here:

As far as booting, check for security settings in the BIOS/UEFI for booting from USB as a feature that has to be enabled. This is often disabled for security reasons. It could also simply be boot order - try the F12 key when turning on the machine to see if you can select, or even see, the desired boot device.

Source, the manual for what I believe is your motherboard that I found:

- https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_b650-ae-series_e_1101_v1.pdf?v=cda9c36c6ea9fe13e74a427bcd197645

As for your other issues:

1. Regarding the PSU - this is a standard modern cooling procedure done by a PSU to save power. The model PSU you have has a "zero rpm" feature, confirming this.

   Sources:

   - https://www.newegg.com/corsair-rmx-series-rm850x-cp-9020200-na-850w/p/N82E16817139272?Item=N82E16817139272
   - https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/757xqx/psu_fan_spins_then_stops/
2. When motherboards display (OC) next to RAM speeds, the intention is that the motherboard and RAM can be overclocked to reach the stated speed. Your machine originally showed a speed of 3600 because this is the maximnum speed the motherboard supports by default, and your RAM is capable of 5600. Since the motherboard was not overclocked, the RAM clocks down to match the memory socket.

   Source:

   - https://www.reddit.com/r/PcBuild/comments/i32qvm/what_does_oc_mean_on_motherboards_specs_for_ram/

Some further details that could help:

Is the USB installer known good and functioning? Sometimes there are issues when writing ISO to a USB for example, depending on the software used.

For my last USB OS install I used balenaEtcher and it worked well: https://www.balena.io/etcher/

I hope this helps.